# How format this REST URL

Tags: rest

I have a model Locker. These lockers can get time-limeted codes to open them. If I put a button on my page I want to call a URL to SMS or email such a code to someone selected in a popupmenu. I need to send both the ID of the locker (eg "123") and the ID of the person (eg "456)

The best I came up with is:

[www.myapp.com/locker/123/person/456/sms](http://www.myapp.com/locker/123/person/456/sms)

[www.myapp.com/locker/123/person/456/email](http://www.myapp.com/locker/123/person/456/email)

Is this good REST practice or am I seeing things wrong and are there better ways

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer this question for 'email'. My answer for 'sms' would be similar.

In REST API design, you always have to answer the question "which resource am I creating, getting, updating or deleting"? In this particular case, I see two options:

1. You create an Email resource. In my perception, the Email is not part of a locker, nor part of a person, rather it is part of a person's inbox, like this:

`POST www.myapp.com/inboxes/456`

The locker ID 123 would be included in the message body (payload) or in the query string (`?locker=123`).

2. If you're not really creating or updating a resource, but instead you are executing a task not affecting any resource, the REST API style is in fact not appropriate. To admit this fact and show the non-REST nature of the call, you could have a URI like this:

`POST www.myapp.com/code-mailer?locker=123&person=456`